# How to set itemValue of a radio button with the value of a text field

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, radio-button, selectoneradio

I have the following radio button scenario:

```
O picked up
O sent to ordering person
O sent to owner
O sent to support group : "here is a text field where to specify the address"
```

The corresponding code is:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{detailModel.afterObject.deliveryAddress}">
    <f:selectItem id="pickedUp" itemValue="picked up" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressPickedUp}"/>
    <f:selectItem id="send2OrderingPerson" itemValue="send 2 ordering person" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressSend2OrderingPerson}"/>
    <f:selectItem id="send2SubscrOwner" itemValue="send 2 subscription owner" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressSend2SubscrOwner}"/>
    <f:selectItem id="send2SupportGroup" itemValue="here should go the content of deliveryAddress1" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressSend2SupportGroup}"/>
    <td>
        <h:inputText id="deliveryAddress1" value="#{detailModel.afterObject.deliveryAddress}"/>
    </td>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I don't know if this is what I really want, but anyway I would like to see if/how it is possible to "copy/reference" the value of a text field into an `itemValue` of a radio button.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display what user enter in the inputtext in the itemvalue of selectitem?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is it possible?